# Why is <hr> tag taking white space rather than taking the background color

Tags: html, css

The hr tag is taking white space rather than the background-color - I tried to solve but I couldn't.

```css
.top {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 100px;
  background-color: #cbf1f5;
}

.mid {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #cbf1f5;
}

.bottom {}

.h1 {
  font-family: 'Sacramento', cursive;
  text-align: center;
}

.firstP {
  text-align: center;
}

.TopCloud {
  position: absolute;
  right: 250px;
  top: 50px;
}

.BottomCloud {
  position: absolute;
  left: 240px;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

h3 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

hr {}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Abdullatif Albahar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sacramento&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>



  <div class="top">
    <img class="TopCloud" src="images/cloud.png" alt="Cloud">
    <h1 class="h1">Abdullatif Albahar</h1>
    <p class="firstP">A Web Developer</p>
    <img class="BottomCloud" src="images/cloud.png" alt="Cloud">
    <br><br><br><br><br>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="mid">
    <div class="profile">

      <img class="moon" src="images/real moon.png" alt="Me">
      <h2>Hi.</h2>
      <p>I am Abdullatif, and I am a beginner Full Stack Web Developer.</p>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="skills">
      <h2>My Skills.</h2>
      <div class="skill row">
        <img class="web dev" src="images/web dev.png" alt="">
        <h3>Web Development</h3>
        <p>.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="skill row 2">
        <img class="web design" src="images/web design.png" alt="">
        <h3>Web Design</h3>
        <p>.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="contact me">
      <h2>Get In Touch</h2>
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, non elit.</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in quis, aenean amet. Phasellus sodales, tellus donec dui, ornare erat.</p>
      <a class="button" href="mailto:name@email.com">Contact Me</a>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="bottom-container">
    <!--make instagram & Twitter accounts for business-->
    <!-- add links -->
    <a class="footer-link" href="">Instagram</a>
    <a class="footer-link" href="">Fiverr</a>
    <a class="footer-link" href="">Freelancer</a>
    <a class="footer-link" href="">Upwork</a>
    <a class="footer-link" href="">Toptal</a>
    <a class="footer-link" href="">Truelancer</a>
    <p>© 2020 Abdullatif Albahar.</p>
  </div>

</html>
```

Comment: because its not inside the blue divs its on body, body is white

Comment: It 's between the divs with the background-color nit inside of it.. thats why

Comment: thank u sooo much , appreciate it

Answer (score 3):

please remove `margin` in `hr`

```css
.top {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 100px;
  background-color: #cbf1f5;
}

.mid {
text-align: center;
background-color: #cbf1f5;
}

.bottom {

}

.h1 {
  font-family: 'Sacramento', cursive;
  text-align: center;
}

.firstP {
  text-align: center;
}

.TopCloud {
  position: absolute;
  right: 250px;
  top: 50px;
}
.BottomCloud{
  position: absolute;
left: 240px;
}
h2{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

h3{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
hr{

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Abdullatif Albahar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sacramento&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>



  <div class="top">
    <img class="TopCloud" src="images/cloud.png" alt="Cloud">
    <h1 class="h1">Abdullatif Albahar</h1>
    <p class="firstP">A Web Developer</p>
      <img class="BottomCloud" src="images/cloud.png" alt="Cloud">
    <br><br><br><br><br>
</div>
<hr style="margin:0;">
  <div class="mid">
    <div class="profile">

      <img  class="moon"src="images/real moon.png" alt="Me">
      <h2>Hi.</h2>
      <p>I am Abdullatif, and I am a beginner Full Stack Web Developer.</p>
    </div>
    <hr class>
    <div class="skills">
      <h2>My Skills.</h2>
      <div class="skill row">
        <img class="web dev" src="images/web dev.png" alt="">
        <h3>Web Development</h3>
        <p>.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="skill row 2">
        <img class="web design" src="images/web design.png" alt="">
        <h3>Web Design</h3>
        <p>.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="contact me">
      <h2>Get In Touch</h2>
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, non elit.</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in quis, aenean amet. Phasellus sodales, tellus donec dui, ornare erat.</p>
      <a class="button" href="mailto:name@email.com">Contact Me</a>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="bottom-container">
    <!--make instagram & Twitter accounts for business-->
    <!-- add links -->
    <a class="footer-link" href="">Instagram</a>
    <a class="footer-link" href="">Fiverr</a>
    <a class="footer-link" href="">Freelancer</a>
    <a class="footer-link" href="">Upwork</a>
    <a class="footer-link" href="">Toptal</a>
    <a class="footer-link" href="">Truelancer</a>
    <p>© 2020 Abdullatif Albahar.</p>
  </div>

</html>
```

Comment: Please check @Abdullatif Albahar

Comment: Welcomes you too

Answer (score 1):

The CSS margin property is used to add space around the hr tag by default. We have to overwrite The CSS margin value to remove white space.
Please include below CSS in your styling :-

```
hr{ margin:0px;}
```

Comment: Welcome you too. Please vote me If the answer is useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the `<hr>` tag has some default CSS.

The `<hr>` tag is taking white space rather than the background-color because the first `<hr>` tag is outside the div so background CSS is not applied on theirs.

To solve this problem you have two solutions-
First: Add css `margin:0;` to `<hr>` tag
Second: Add a wrapper div and apply `background-color` CSS to that div